# How to compare r-squared from different ANOVAs?

Tags: statistics, regression, anova

I'm trying to compare the variance explained by one factor in ANOVA, across three different experimental conditions. For each condition I performed the same ANOVA, and r squared = SS_factor/SS_total. Is there a way to compared the different r squared values for different conditions?

If not, what is the best way to make the comparison between conditions in the case? Thanks!